# Why does FACK decides a segment is lost when snd.fack beyond snd.nxt?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

In FACK paper(MM' 96), I don't understand this statement:
if the sender receives an ACK which advances snd.fack beyond the value of snd.nxt at the time a segment was retransmitted (and that retransmitted segment is otherwise unaccounted for), the sender knows that segment which was retransmitted has been lost.

Could someone give more explanations or example about this?
MM96 link:
[FACK MM96](http://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/1996/papers/mathis.pdf)